# Trim function does not remove all occurances of character?

Tags: php, trim

Why do I get this result when doing a `trim()`?

```
trim( '18" x 24"', '"' )
```

The result is `18" x 24` whereas my expected result is `18 x 24`. It only removed the last `"` of the string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: I'd give you the answer, but everyone and their mother already did.

Comment: ...reading the documentation is always a start...

Comment: yep, i already read the documentation. it was just that I had a wrong logic in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) only removes the specified characters from the beginning and end of the string. If you want to remove them everywhere in the string, use [`str_replace()`](http://th.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$doublequotes_removed = str_replace('"', '', '18" x 24"');
```

Answer (score 1):

`trim` pulls the relevent characters off of the beginning and end.

You are looking for `str_replace`

```
str_replace('"','','18" x 24"');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use str_replace()
it will replace your specified character with another one..

like this

```
str_replace('"','',''18" x 24");
```

you will get desired output..